# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager getting shutdown

Tags: apache, pooling

I am trying to use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in my application to invoke / call some web-services.

The particular connection manager is configured as a spring bean like below:

```
<bean id="httpConnectionManager" class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager" >
        <property name="defaultMaxPerRoute" value="10" />
        <property name="maxTotal" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

I am using the above as a dependency in one of my other beans as follows:

```
private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

 public void setPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager   poolingHttpClientConnectionManager)
    {
        this.poolingHttpClientConnectionManager = poolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
    }
```

I am using the above to get a CloseableHttpClient object as follows:

```
private CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient()
{
        return HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(this.httpConnectionManager).build();
}
```

However, i always see an exception message like this with above configuration: 'Connection pool shut down'

Can someone please help with the above.

Regards